# Lex won't recognize double operators- !=, :=, <<, etc. Can I give a Lex expression precedence?

Tags: parsing, flex-lexer, lex

Trying to parse operators (+, -, =, <<, !=), using states like

```
%{
%}
OP  ["+"|";"|":"|","|"*"|"/"|"="|"("|")"|"{"|"}"|"*"|"@"|"$"|
"<"|">"|"&"|"|"|"!"|]
DOUBOP [":="|".."|"<<"|">>"|"<>"|"<="|">="|"=>"|"**"|"!="|"{:"|"}:"|"\-"]
```

and later on

```
{DOUBOP} { printf("%s (operator)\n", yytext); }
{OP} { printf("%s (operator)\n", yytext); }
```

but Lex is identifying operators like "<<" as "<" and "<". I thought since it was in double quotes this would work, but I see that's not the case.

Is there anyway I can give a regular expression precedence, ie have lex check for a double operator first, and then a single operator?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[...]` is a character class, not an eccentric type of parenthesis. If you want to parenthesize a sub-expression in a pattern, use ordinary parentheses. In this case, however, parentheses are not necessary. (Indeed, most of the quotes aren't necessary either, but they don't hurt and some of them would be useful.)

`"=="` recognises the two character-sequence consisting of two equal signs. `"=="|"++"` recognizes either two equal signs or two plus signs.

By contrast, `["=="]` recognises a single character, which could be either a quote or an equals sign. Since a character class is a set, the fact that each of those appears twice is irrelevant (although I think it would save a lot of grief if flex issued a warning). Similarly, `["=="|"<<"]` recognises a single character if it is a quote, an equals sign, a vertical bar or a less than sign.

Flex pattern syntax is documented in the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html). It differs in a few ways from regexes in other systems, so it's worth reading the short document. However, character classes are mostly the same in all regex syntaxes in common use, especially the use of square brackets to delimit the set.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to put all single characters together, and run the `*` command on the end up curly braces.
i.e.

```
OP  ["+"|";"|":"|","|"*"|"/"|"="|"("|")"|"{"|"}"|"*"|"@"|"$"|
"<"|">"|"&"|"|"|"!"|]*
```